# Rails passing attributes to nested modals with foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have the following code. In the first modal that comes up I'm listing all of the user's images. When they click on one of the images it triggers the second modal and I want the id of the image to be available to me. But it's always coming back as the id of the last image.

```
<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<% if signed_in? %>
<h4>Your Images</h4>
<div class="dashboard-panel">
<% @assets.each do |asset| %>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal" onclick="<% @selected_asset = asset.id %>"><%= image_tag asset.file_name.url(:dashboard).to_s %></a>
<%= asset.id %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% else %>
You don't have any images.
<% end %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="secondModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
  <p>Asset id is <%= @selected_asset.inspect %></p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

I think there is something wrong with my structure but I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

The html of the second modal is only generated once. The value of @selected_asset will be the id of the last asset in the loop. One option is to generate a separate modal for each image, something like this:

```
<% @assets.each do |asset| %>
  <a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal-<%= asset.id %>Click</a>
  <div id="secondModal-<%= asset.id %>" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
    <p>Asset id is <%= asset.id %></p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note the inclusion of asset.id in the id of the modal so they are all unique